# Error in Select multi Column from Subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2016

I wrote following SQL command

```
select * from [Monitoring].[dbo].[MaintTaskMonitor]  
where (JobStartDate,TaskType) in (
select max(JobStartDate),TaskType  from [Monitoring].[dbo].[MaintTaskMonitor]  where systemname='Dido'
group by TaskType)
```

which gave the following error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

Where is the problem from?

Comment: `where (JobStartDate,TaskType) in (` I don't believe that SQL Server allows this syntax. As far as I know you cannot `where` on 2 columns, maybe a cross apply could help here

Comment: yeah, a tupled where is not allowed (yet). you can probably solve this by doing: `select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by tasktype order by jobstartdate desc) as sort from your table y) y where y.sort = 1` although, your version will generated multiple rows if max date is duplicated which mine wont

Comment: The [`IN` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) doesn't work like that, the subquery is meant to have a single column only. Have you considered a [`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins) instead?

Comment: IIRC, MySQL and postgresql both allow this, hence the confusion, but it's not actually standard SQL.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, it's part of a described optional feature. "Without Feature F561, “Full value expressions”, conforming SQL language shall not contain a <row value expression> immediately contained in an <in value list> that is not a <value specification>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, instead, switch to a correlated subquery and then check the value of `JobStartDate` from the outer scope matches the `MAX` value of the inner scope in the `HAVING`:

```sql
USE Monitoring; --Connect to the correct database instead, no need for 3 part naming
GO

SELECT <Explicit Column List> --Get out of the habit of using *
FROM [dbo].[MaintTaskMonitor] MTM
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [dbo].[MaintTaskMonitor] sq
              WHERE sq.systemname = 'Dido'
                AND sq.TaskType = MTM.TaskType
              HAVING MAX(sq.JobStartDate) = MTM.JobStartDate);
```